how to change size of symbol in ggplot2 when size, shape, and color are set through geom_point?
The problem i am having is surely trivial, and yet i am unable to solve it. What i need is to have my own shape, colour, and size for the geom_point(). However, if i set it, the size of the symbols in the legend is not changing.
So, say i want to plot this:
library("ggplot2")

x <- rnorm(2000, 0, 1)
y <- rnorm(2000, 0, 1)
category <- sample(c("one", "two"), 2000, replace = TRUE)
size <- rnorm(2000, 0, 1)*10

df <- data.frame(x, y, category, size)

dev.new()

ggplot(df, aes(x=x, y=y, color=category)) +
    geom_point(size = df$size) +
    guides(color = guide_legend(override.aes = list(size = 10)))

But then, if i want to change the aesthetic of my geom_point(), i am unable to set the size of the dots in the legend. In other words, this is not working anymore:
dev.new()
ggplot(df, aes(x=x, y=y, fill=category)) +
    geom_point(shape=21, colour="black", size = df$size) +
    guides(color = guide_legend(override.aes = list(size = 10)))

I feel like i should pass more parameters to guides but maybe not. What to do?
I can't find any answer for my question. If you do, please mark this as duplicate and link it. Thank you!
EDIT:
the expected output is represented by the second plot i provided (where i set the aesthetic for geom_point()) but then i need the dots in the legend as big as i want.
EDIT 2:
using sample instead of rnorm (as suggested in a comment) gives the same problem, it seems:
library("ggplot2")

x <- sample(2000, 1000, replace=T)
y <- sample(2000, 1000, replace=T)
category <- sample(c("one", "two"), 2000, replace = TRUE)
size <- sample(2000, 1000, replace=T)/50

df <- data.frame(x, y, category, size)

dev.new()

ggplot(df, aes(x=x, y=y, color=category)) +
    geom_point(size = df$size) +
    guides(color = guide_legend(override.aes = list(size = 10)))

dev.new()

ggplot(df, aes(x=x, y=y, fill=category)) +
    geom_point(shape=21, colour="black", size = df$size) +
    guides(color = guide_legend(override.aes = list(size = 10)))


Perhaps: ggplot(df, aes(x=x, y=y, color=category, size = size)) +   geom_point() is what you are looking for? Not entirely clear what expected output is desired.

@Peter no, that is not the expected behaviour. i need to set the aesthetic in the geom_point() part of the plot. and yet have control over the size of the dots in the final legend. this is what is not working: i can't set the size in the legend.

So if I understand you correctly you want the size of the points to vary in the plot with df$size but in the legend you want the size key to be consistent i.e. one size only or something else?

yes, and that size should be one that i chose. i expected it to work using guides...override but it is not. this is apparently happening after i apply color and shape in the geom_point part.

Half the time size will be negative since it's drawn from a normal distribution. I didn't check if that's the cause for the error but it doesn't seem right.

@RuiBarradas, that is just an example...my real data are always positive. i can try though.

@Peter already tried that, still not working!

Maybe this helps?
library(ggplot2)

set.seed(213)
x <- rnorm(2000, 0, 1)
y <- rnorm(2000, 0, 1)
category <- sample(c("one", "two"), 2000, replace = TRUE)
size <- rnorm(2000, 0, 1)*10


ggplot(df, aes(x = x, y=y, fill = category)) +
geom_point(shape = 21, aes(size = size)) +
  guides(fill = guide_legend(override.aes = list(size = 5)),
         size  = "none")



yes! this is indeed working...but why? why did you set size="none"?

That is a parameter inside the guides() call to specify that there should be no size legend, just one for fill. (There is no color mapping inside an aes() so the color part inside guides() here is probably redundant.)

@JonSpring Thanks for the comment: you are correct colour argument to guides() is redundant - I was just lifting the code from the OP eg. @gabt setting guides(size = "none"), as @JonSpring notes is the argument to stop the size related legend from being revealed.
